# Incompatible types. Required: T, Found T. Why?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, hashmap

I am trying to build a service Locator using generics and I'm getting warnings by the compiler at 
`objects.put(klass, value)`
It says incompatible types, Required: T. Found: T.

```
public class SimpleServiceLocator <T> implements ServiceLocator<T> {
    private HashMap<Class, Factory> services = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Class, T> objects = new HashMap<>();


    @Override
    public <T> void setService(Class<T> klass, Factory<T> factory) throws LocatorError {
        if (services.containsKey(klass)) throw new LocatorError();
        services.put(klass, factory);
    }



    @Override
    public <T> T getObject(Class<T> klass) throws LocatorError {
        if (services.containsKey(klass)) {
            Factory factory = services.get(klass);
            return (T) factory.create(this);
        } else if(objects.containsKey(klass)) {
            return (T) objects.get(klass);
        }
        throw new LocatorError();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void setConstant(Class<T> klass, T value) throws LocatorError {
        if (objects.containsKey(klass)) throw new LocatorError();
        objects.put(klass, value);
    }
}
```

And the Interface is:

```
public interface ServiceLocator <T>{
    <T> void setService(Class<T> klass, Factory<T> factory)
            throws LocatorError;

    <T> void setConstant(Class<T> klass, T value)
            throws LocatorError;

    <T> T getObject(Class<T> klass)
            throws LocatorError;
}
```

Comment: Why do you define a new generic type `T` for each method?

Comment: The interface was given to me by my teacher, so I have to make it work like that.

Comment: Nope, I doubt that your teacher gave you exactly that interface. It is very unlikely they gave you exactly these generic type definitions.

Comment: Doubt whatever you want, but that is what I was given to work with

Comment: Don't manipulate your question when there is already an answer.

Comment: What Tom wanted to point out: It does not make sense that way. I would remove the extra generic in front of each method so that you get a normal generic interface. 
In case you want to have these extra types: Just give it a different name. Else you get messages like Required T found T :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined multiple generic types with the same name.

`public class SimpleServiceLocator <T>`

defines a generic type `T` at the class level

`<T> void setService`

defines a generic type `T` at the function level

If you use `T` inside your functions, you will use the `T` from your function definition, which is different from the type you used to declare your `HashMap`

Comment: Should I redefine the hashmap and the class header like this?
    'public class SimpleServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator{
        private HashMap<Class, Factory> services = new HashMap<>();
        private HashMap<Class, Object> objects = new HashMap<>();'

Comment: I think you want to remove the generic type definition (`<T>`) from your functions. But I don't know what you want to build ...